# difference between new ArrayList<String>() and new ArrayList()

Tags: java, generics

What's the difference between the two declarations?

```
new ArrayList<String>();
new ArrayList();
```

They work, but the second one returns a warning. I don't understand why.

I understand the difference between `ArrayList<String> arr` and `ArrayList arr`, the first enables a type checking control. But what about `new ArrayList<String>()` and `new ArrayList()`? Is there any difference at implementation level? What do I lose in terms of controls?

Comment: It detects the type if you use the `<>` diamond operator, like `List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();`

Answer (score 3):

In Java 7 it can detect the type automatically, but you'll need to use the [Diamond Operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html):

```
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
```

It's basically syntactic sugar for the first line. Without the diamond operator, it's a raw type (a non-parameterized generic type). Raw types exist for compatibility with older Java versions that don't support generics but will cause warnings when used.

Comment: Even though this is true, it doesn't answer the question asked: "What is the difference between `ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>()` and `ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList();`?"..

Comment: @kapep I got it, but I don't understand yet what I lose, in terms of compiler checkings, coding `ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList();`. I mean, if I code in this way doing `arr.add(arr.get(0))` dosn't return an error.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before, this can be resolved using the `<>` diamond operator.

But there are reasons why this is so. You have to keep in mind that generics where added **after** the collection classes. And the idea was they generics should not break existing source code. Sun didn't want that customers would all of a sudden fail when compiling tons and tons of existing code using un-generified lists ...

So the java compilers had to accept code like `... = new ArrayList()`. 
But the point is, that this kind of declaration creates a so called "raw type".

And if possible, you should never ever use raw types. And that is why eclipse and javac give you warnings - to remind you to never create raw types.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know that at runtime, all generics are erased, so that all ArrayLists are of the same type, no matter what you put into your < >.

So while the second line is possible (for historic reasons, before generics were possible), it should be avoided because it obfuscates the types.